# Convert XLS that contains HTML to a clean CSV

Tags: html, csv, converters, xls, data-cleaning

I have received a very big file (340 rows) from someone that I need to convert to a clean CSV. I tried: Opening in notepad and saving as CSV, in notepad the data looked like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th filter=all>Salutation</th>
        <th filter=all>FirstName</th>
        <th filter=all>Last Name</th>
        <th filter=all>Email</th>
        <th><filter=all>Organisation Name</th>
```

Does anyone know how to get this into CSV format and getting rid of all the HTML?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by „clean CSV“? Do you want to remove all the HTML content?

Comment: I'd need to see the entire file but this doesn't seem too difficult to me (depending on what your demands are for the CSV file). But first I need access to the whole file.